# Xcode .aspectFill tilts code on iPad and iPhone X

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have made a game routine in `Swift 4`.
**GameScene.SKS** is set up for resolution `750x1334`.
When I'm testing, the code goes on `iPad` and on `iPhone X`.

For example, when a `SpriteNode` hits a "`dirt boulder`", the sprite node must stop. I've solved this in the code by testing `SKPhysicsContact`. When a `spriteNode` hits a "`dirt boulder`", the `SpriteNode` is located just up to the "`dirt boulder`" from the direction the `spriteNode` came from. This occurs by correction of the **x** and **y** coordinates of the sprite node.

It works fine on iPhone SE, 5, 6, 7 and 8. However, on the different iPad and iPhone X, the code moves so that when the `SpriteNode` hits a "dirt Boulder", the `SpriteNode` will be located on the opposite side of the "`dirt Boulder`" - so the code works the opposite ...

In **GameViewController.swift**, I have used this code to customize **GameScene.sks** to the different devices:

```
if let view = self.view as! SKView? {
    if let scene = SKScene (fileNamed: "GameScene") {
        scene.scaleMode = .aspectfill
        view.presentScene (scene)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's `if easy scene = SKScene` supposed to be? Also, `if let view = self.view as! SKView?` doesn't make sense. You don't have to force cast in an `if-let`, and why `SKView?`. Change that to `if let view = self.view as? SKView {`

Comment: Did change code in question... dont work...